# C# Need to deserialize dynamic JSON to bind to ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, listview, dynamic

I have JSON in the following format:

```
{
    "fields": 
    [
        "field_a",
        "field_b"
    ],
    "records": 
    [
        [
            1203,
            169
        ],
        [
            983,
            147
        ]
    ]
}
```

which I need to de-serialize and bind to an ASP.NET ListView, where 'fields' becoming the column headings, and 'records' becoming the rows of data.

In this case, I would have a table:

```
field_a | field_b
-----------------
1203    | 169
983     | 147
```

I am currently using Newtonsoft JSON library to de-serialize, but can't figure out how to map a dynamic number of fields into a C# object that is ultimately bind-able to the web control.

Answer (score 0):

I think you pretty much used the keyword in your question. Dynamic baby. here is an example to get you started.

```
var text = "{\"fields\": [\"field_a\",\"field_b\"],\"records\": [[1203,169],[983,147]]}";
dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text);
var fields = result.fields;
var records = result.records;
var columnList = new List<Column>();

for (var x = 0; x < fields.Count; x++)
{
    var field = fields[x];
    var col = new Column() {Title = field.Value};
    columnList.Add(col);
    var record = records[x];
    for (var y = 0; y < record.Count; y++)
    {
        var value = record[y];
        var cell = new Cell() {Value = (int)value.Value};
        col.Cells.Add(cell);
    }
}
```

and the classes to match:

```
public class Column
{
    public Column()
    {
        Cells = new List<Cell>();
    }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Cell> Cells { get; set; }
}

public class Cell
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

This is just an example.  I am not sure how you want your classes to look but this would be a start.  Hopefully this helps.